# Should I be using nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text)) for everything I echo/print to screen?

Tags: php, database, string, htmlspecialchars

Title kinda says it all. Should I be using nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text)) for everything I echo/print to screen?

I've been looking around, and it seems like the word is that when handling input from the user, sanitize it by escaping it and inserting it into the database. Then when retrieving from the database, if I intend to spit it out to the screen, I should use htmlspecialchars() to convert unfriendly characters to their safe equivalents, and use nl2br() around that if I want to convert newlines to breaks?

Should I just create a new function called safeEcho() that does `echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text))` and use that everywhere I might have to output something that could have come from the user, instead of the usual echo/print statements then?

Comment: Only a Sith deals in absolutes.

Comment: Note that when you're storing strings to the database, you should use mysql_real_escape_string as vlzvl stated below. Nevertheless, when you `echo` the actual string to the user, you should use those. Also, look into using templating engines such as Smarty (http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape) to do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no,
to save safely in your database you only need this: (to escape single/double quotes & other)

```
mysql_real_escape_string($thedata);
```

when reading from database, dont do anything; many conversions dont do any good.

the nl2br just takes the "\n" and produces a `<br \>`; surely non needed for printing..

Comment: You should also look into the mysqli (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) module, which has for the most part superseded the mysql module and is also a functional superset.

Comment: Hmm hey @vlzvl so you're saying that I shouldn't bother using the htmlspecialchars() when outputting? I thought some people mention that you should or else if someone inserts code, it would get rendered by the browser?

Comment: it depends; you're providing ways for someone enter his own HTML? then you should use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to efficiently strip'em'all and allow only your own.

Comment: This is ridiculous. You should always sanitize any user input that you output or you're wide open to XSS.